# Динамический межстрочный интервал

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Есть элемент с заранее известной высотой, но не известным текстом внутри. Необходимо динамически рассчитывать межстрочный интервал для текста, чтобы заполнить весь элемент по высоте. Каким образом это делается ? 
Пример кода:

```css
.table_otvod {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border: none; 
  border-spacing: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  height:320px;
  width:100%;
}

.table_otvod td{
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
   width:33.33%
}

.table_otvod tr{
vertical-align: top;
}

.table_otvod ul{
  text-align: left;
  list-style-image: url(MyURL);
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.table_otvod span{
padding-left: 20px;

}
```

```html
<table class="table_otvod">
  <tbody><tr>
  
  <td><h3>Продукт </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Текст 1</span></li>
      <li><span>Очень длинный текст в несколько строк 11111</span></li>
      <li><span>Текст 1</span></li>
      <li><span>Текст 1</span></li>
    </ul>  
    </td>
    <td>
    
    <h3>Сервис</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Очень длинный текст в несколько строк 11111</span></li>
      <li><span>Очень длинный текст в несколько строк 11111</span></li>

    </ul>  
    
    </td>
    <td>
    
        <h3>Условия</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Чуть короче текст213213213213</span></li>
      <li><span>Чуть короче текст</span></li>
      <li><span>Чуть короче текст</span></li>
      <li><span>Чуть короче текст</span></li>
    </ul>  
    
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 шаг. Посчитать количество строк в тексте.**
Делается этот так:
Выводим текст в обычный `div` без фиксированной высоты и берём его высоту `(H)`.
Высота конкретной строчки нам известна `(lineHeight)`.
На основе этих данных расчитываем количество строк = высота блока / высоту строчки.

```
stringNumber = H / lineHeight.
```

**2 шаг. Рассчитываем новую высоту строчки для заполнения блока.**
Высоту блока которую нужно получить `(BH)` делим на количество строчек `(stringNumber)`

```
newLineHeight = BH / stringNumber;
```

---

**Реализация алгоритма**

В данном примере необходимую высоту задаю через кастомный атрибут `myHeight`.
Алгоритм сам находит все блоки с классом `fill` и на основе заданого атрибута рассчитывает их параметры.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("fill");

for (var el of els) {
  MakeFill(el);
}

function GetStringsNumber(el) {
  var height = el.clientHeight;
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  var lineHeightStr = style.getPropertyValue('line-height');
  var lineHeight = +lineHeightStr.substring(0,lineHeightStr.length-2);
  var linesNumber = height / lineHeight;
  return linesNumber;
}

function MakeFill(el) {
  var height = +el.getAttribute("myHeight");
  var stringNumber = GetStringsNumber(el);
  var lineHeight = height / stringNumber;
  el.style.lineHeight = lineHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
.fill {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fill" myHeight="120">
  Привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет
</div>

<div class="fill" myHeight="150">
  Привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет
</div>

<div class="fill" myHeight="70">
  Привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет привет
</div>
```

Кроме того для реального кода необходимо будет ещё учесть `padding`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Ваше решение мне помогло. Адаптировал идею и код под себя, задачу решил.

Answer (score 2):

Задача легко решается с помощью `display: flex`, тк он заполняет все свое "главное направление"(flex-direction), и если оно будут вертикальным (`flex-direction: row`), то блок будет распространятся на всю высоту, например:

```css
.items {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
height:320px;
}
.item {
flex-grow: 1;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
border: 1px solid #222;
}
.item p {
border: 1px solid #921;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
<div class="item">
 <h2>Header</h2>
 <p>12312<br>3123</p>
 <p>123</p>
 <p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
 <h2>Header</h2>
 <p>123</p>
 <p>12222<br>3333</p>
 <p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
 <h2>Header</h2>
 <p>123</p>
 <p>123</p>
 <p>12222<br>33333</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дело в том что заранее не известно разбиение на строки. В вашем примере это уже сделано через `p` и `br` а в вопросе это просто текст, которые не разбит на отдельные строки. По крайней мере я так понял вопрос. Если же разбиение заранее есть, то ваш вариант думаю оптимальный.